# DateTime.today() runs differently in administrator

Tags: c#, datetime

I live in Canada, the `DateTime.Today` format is recorded as `dd/mm/yyyy`.  It is strange when I run the application as administrator, it records the DateTime.`Today` format as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Is there anyway I can do a check?  Or it is the computer datetime setting?

Comment: Yes, that depends on the culture and date format set by the user in the Windows settings

Comment: By the way, be aware, custom date and time format strings _are_ case sensitive. `mm` is for minutes for example, `MM` for months.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A DateTime object isn't internally represented in days and months, so it doesn't actually have any native format per se. (There also isn't a `DateTime.Today()` method, but rather a property `DateTime.Today`)

A DateTime (which DateTime.Today returns an instance of) does have a `ToString()` method which is declared as:

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return DateTimeFormat.Format(this, (string) null, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo);
}
```

That `CurrentInfo` is going to be different for different users on the machine. Some operations will implicitly call `ToString()` (eg `Console.WriteLine`)

The good news is that there are overloads for `ToString()`, so you can do something like

```
Console.Write(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

(Or any `IFormatProvider`)

Comment: Thanks I force it to display as dt.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");  and it works.   Both show same results in administrator and normal user mode.